# Google Sheets: how to SUM multiple criteria (AND of OR) where the OR comparisons are strings?

Tags: google-sheets

For example in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/179oMZ1h8cHC9T2yKotsmV9hdpDMIzLM9EOPW-vpobkg/edit#gid=2085573974

I want the sum of `Hours` where `Status` = `TODO` or `INPROGRESS` **and** `Location` = `NYC` or `LA`

Hope I phrased the question clearly enough and thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Which do you want, Google-sheets or Excel?  The approach to each are different.

Comment: Google Sheets, per my example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Query:

```
=sum(QUERY(A2:D8,"Select C where (B = 'TODO' OR B = 'INPROGRESS') AND (D = 'NYC' or D = 'LA')"))
```

[image]